# Add schemaLocation to XML serializing List<T> using XmlSerializer

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to add `schemaLocation` attribute to XML root element when serializing `List<T>`. Code works fine if I'm serializing just one object but does not work on lists. My current code:

```
public class SomeObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class XmlListContainer<T> : List<T>
{
    [XmlAttribute(Namespace = XmlSchema.InstanceNamespace)]
    public string schemaLocation = "http :// localhost/someschema";
}
public class BuildXml
{
    public static void GetXml()
    {
        var list = new XmlListContainer<SomeObject>()
        {
            new SomeObject() { Id = 1, Name = "One" },
            new SomeObject() { Id = 2, Name = "Two" },
        };
        var objectToXml = list;
        string output;
        using (var writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            var xs = new XmlSerializer(objectToXml.GetType());
            var nameSpaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            nameSpaces.Add("xsi", "http :// www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
            xs.Serialize(writer, objectToXml, nameSpaces);
            output = writer.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
            writer.Close();
        }
        Console.WriteLine(output);
    }
}
```

XML root element appears without `schemaLocation`:

```
<ArrayOfSomeObject xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

If I'm changing code to

```
public class SomeObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(Namespace = XmlSchema.InstanceNamespace)]
    public string schemaLocation = "http :// localhost/someschema";
}
...
var objectToXml = new SomeObject() { Id = 1, Name = "One" };
```

...all looks fine but I need list list

```
<SingleObject xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://localhost/someschema">
```

Is it possible to add `schemaLocation` attribute when serializing `List<T>`?

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: An XML file can have only one root tag.  You list is creating  multiple root tags.  Add a root tag before adding your list.

Comment: jdweng, there is just one root tag, named ArrayOfSomeObject in current version.